# ScrollEvent doesn't fire if DragEvent is running

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `ControlsFX GridView`, which hold images in it's cells, and each one of these images can be reordered / multiple images at one time.

This all works fine, however, when needing to scroll down the `GridView`, while also dragging one of the images, is proving tricky:

Mockup :

[image: Mockup]

It seems that my issue isn't so much one that is specific to me, but seems more like `ScrollEvents` do not fire during `DragEvents`.

Is that the case, or is there a way to handle both at the same time?

***More Information:***

Ideally, I would like the `ScrollEvent` event to still fire, so that I can just programmatically move the scrollbar on the `GridView`, however, when there is a `DragEvent`, it seems that my `ScrollEvent` event doesn't fire.

My `ScrollEvent` is:

```
public void watchSceneMouseWheelEvents(AppModel app) {
        //getScene() gets the main scene, set in app model.
        app.getScene().setOnScroll((ScrollEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Mouse wheel scrolling.");
            event.consume();
        });
    }
```

This works fine, and I get `Mouse wheel scrolling.` in my console whenever and wherever in the scene that I scroll the mouse wheel, and obviously, that means it fires when inside the `GridView` and actually scrolling through the `GridView`.

But as soon as I am dragging an image, `ScrollEvent` stop firing, and there doesn't appear to be anything in the `DragEvents` that should prevent any `ScrollEvent`.

I looked for a way to detect just the mousewheel scrolling on it's own without it being on the scene but haven't been able to find anything.

I've also had another solution in place where the images would be dragged to the top or bottom edges of the app, and this would cause the scroll, though, this didn't/doesn't work smoothly, so I have removing it for now while I try and get the more straight forward option working.

Has anyone ever had the same issue / is there a best practice approach to resolve this?

Any guidance, tips, pointers would be very welcomed!!!